# Is there a codec to preview Panasonic rw2 files in Windows Explorer for a 64-bit version of Windows?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-explorer, preview, image-viewer

Have you been able to find a Panasonic .rw2 image file codec to view rw2 images in explorer?

(Before you answer, make sure it's for 64 bit :+>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [FastPictureViewer codecs](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/)

> FastPictureViewer Codec Pack 2.3
>
> 64-bit and-32 bit image decoders for Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP SP3.
>   Enables support for 38 additional image formats in Windows Explorer, Windows Photo Gallery, Windows Photo Viewer, Windows Live™ Photo Gallery and Windows Media Center 7, all with full native 64-bit support, great file-formats compatibility and proven rock-solid stability and performance.
>   Supports raw formats from more than 320 digital camera models, including CR2, NEF, DNG and more, plus specialists image formats like EXR, TGA

[image]