# Is there a free codec for Windows XP to allow display of RW2 files

Tags: codec, paint.net

Does anyone know of a codec for Windows XP which allows the display of Panasonic RW2 files?
I've seen this link for the [Microsoft Camera Codec Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26829) but it only applies to Windows Vista and later. Also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/179197/is-there-a-codec-to-preview-panasonic-rw2-files-in-windows-explorer-for-a-64-bit) has a link to a site where they charge for the codec, so that's no good :-(

My end goal is to be able to edit my photos in Paint.NET, so maybe there is some plugin for this which enables loading of RW2 files?

Comment: Are you planning to write code to add RW2 support to Paint.NET?  RW2 may be supported by this open source project http://rawstudio.org/. Although it's Linux.  My understanding is most raw formats are based on TIFF.

Comment: gimp for windows?

Comment: I'm not sure if this format is based on tiff or not - picasa seems to display the images with weird distortions suggesting that some information about the lens/focal length is stored in the file too...

Answer (score 2):

[Try the Paint.Net RAW plugin](http://paint.net.amihotornot.com.au/Features/Effects/Plugins/File_Types/Raw_Camera_Images/), probably won't work with RW2 files, but might be worth a try. RW2 is a proprietary RAW file format. You might try renaming the file extension to .raw and try to open them after installing the raw codec.

The plugin has to made for Paint.Net, you can't use just any codec, and it has to be [installed in the Paint.Net program in the proper place](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/1708-how-to-install-pluginsgeneral-plugin-troubleshooting-thread/). More than likely just copy and paste the RAW codecs into the Paint.Net program folder, there should be a sub folder named filetypes.

[PhotoMechanic can edit RW2 files](http://www.camerabits.com/site/downloads.html) starting with version 4.6, they have a support forum also. Not Free though.